# How to read string from Text which saved in Documents Directory with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, documentsdirectory

I have a Test.txt file saved in Documents Directory of an app. There are several names saved one by one in each line in the Test.txt file, like this:

```
Tom
Jack
Jerry
Jennifer
Lynn
```

I would like to add these names to an array, like this:

```
var nameList = ["Tom", "Jack", "Jerry", "Jennifer", "Lynn"]
```

Is there any way to get it work?

I have the following codes, but it will consider the names as one string.

```
  if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let archiveURL = dir.appendingPathComponent("Test").appendingPathExtension("txt")

            do {

                try Data(textView.text.utf8).write(to: archiveURL)
            }

            catch {
                print("error")
            }

            do {
                namesPool = try! [String(contentsOf: archiveURL, encoding: .utf8)]
            }

        }
```

The above codes will get the following array:

```
var nameList = ["Tom\nJack\nJerry\nJennifer\nLynn\n"]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one last step, separate it using:

```
let namesTogether = try! String(contentsOf: archiveURL, encoding: .utf8)
namesPool = namesTogether.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, Milan. I did try this before asking for help, but it will get an error: Value of type '[String]' has no member 'components'.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, check the updated answer

Comment: Oh, man. That’s it. Thank you very very much.

Comment: To be more versatile regarding the new line charachers I'd prefer `components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)`

Comment: @vadian Thanks, Vadian.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
// String with multiple names separated by end of line
let nameStr = try! String(contentsOf: archiveURL, encoding: .utf8)
// array of Substrings
let nameArray = nameStr.split(separator: "\n") 
// first name as String
let name = String(nameArray[0])
```

More about handling strings:[Strings Cheat Sheet](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-string-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tomasz. It works in a way. But I will save some other names to this Test.txt file sometimes. It will get an error: "Cannot assign value of type '[ArraySlice<String>]' to type '[String]'", if the namesPool is dynamic.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

`split(separator:)` returns an array of `Substring`s, instead of `String`s. Considering that `Substring` is supposed to be used as a intermediate type while working with strings (see the link above), in this particular case I would still go with `components(separatedBy:)` since he wants that list of strings as a final result and is not manipulating them further

Comment: @user174782 see edited response